# Are the Knowledge-Base-Article ID numbers, e.g. "KB3198347" more than simple identifiers?

Tags: windows-update

These days, Microsoft Windows Updates have numbers like "KB3198347" .
Do these identifiers (and their corresponding Knowledge-Base-Article  ID numbers) carry some meaning? Like the first digit 3 means "younger than 2010" or something?

Answer (score 0):

Does it matter what the pattern is? People are going to find the articles with search engines. Including Microsoft's own:  http://support.microsoft.com/search

It seems fairly chronological, but only a fraction of the IDs seem to be public. Which does not unusual for an issue tracking system.